# TypeScript constructor mass assignment

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing Data Models for Database with TypeScript, and the code looks really ugly and verbose, is there any shorter version to declare it?

It's for MongoDB, so I would like to have an Interface for raw MongoDB document and the Model class separately. The ugly but working version looks like that

```
interface PostDocument {
  id:   number
  text: string
}

class Post implements PostDocument {
  id:   number
  text: string

  constructor(doc: PostDocument) {
    this.id = doc.id
    this.text = doc.text
  }
}
```

Ideally would be nice to have something like the code below, but I don't know if something like that possible with TypeScript

```
class Model<D> {
  somehow declare properties from D on Model
  constructor(document: D) { Object.assign(this, document)  }
}

interface PostDocument {
  id:   number
  text: string
}

class Post extends Model<PostDocument> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems like it's possible

```
interface ModelConstructor<M, D> { new (document: D): M & D }

abstract class Model<D> {
  constructor(document: D) { Object.assign(this, document) }
}

function buildModel<D extends Object>(): ModelConstructor<Model<D>, D> {
  return Model as any
}

interface PostDocument {
  id:   number
  text: string
}

class Post extends buildModel<PostDocument>() {
}

const document: PostDocument = { id: 5, text: 'something' }
const post = new Post(document)
console.log(post.text)
```